# SQL "IN" Operator

Tags: sql

I have a doubt with the `select` statement query with `in` operator. That is, if I need to get the multiple po values with according to their due nos.  If I do this,

```
select * from table1 where pono in('82200388180','82200388179') and dueno in('001','004')
```

then it works. But I need to clarify with you about one point. assume if i giving like this,

select * from table1 where pono in('82200388180','82200388179') and dueno ('001','004')

(One PO can have Multiple Due Nos. Nothing is unique)

how it works? whether 
1. it returns the row where due no 001 available 
or 
2.it returns the row corresponding to the pono=82200388180 with the dueno=001.

i need to get the answer like option 2. please guide me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to delete a record where `pono` can be `1 and 2` but the dueno should be equal to `001`?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking for. The second query looks just fine. It should still work even if the numbers are both the same - it will still only return rows from table1 with the given dueno-set (even though the set only contains "001")

Comment: Give an example of input and output you want. Your question is not clear.

Comment: What relationship is there between *pono* and *dueno*? one *pono* corresponds to single dueno(ie. one-to-one mapping) or may it one-to-many? please clarify

Comment: I think you should union both two tables to get correct result.

Comment: @Taryn East: ya i agree with you friend. It will return a row. Assume if i have a table with the values like PONo: 1 ,dueno :001,002 and PONo: 2, DueNo:001,003.. Here i need to get the record of PONo1 where the dueno 001 also PONO2 where 001.. Here we may get a conflict right??

Comment: @sachin : No friend One PoNo can have multiple due nos

Comment: @kad1r: how? can u explain me friend

Comment: What DBMS is this for? (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server ...)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the proper po values according to that corresponding due
>   no.

There is no correlation between the positions in the `in` clause.

This will probably give you result you want.

```
select *
from table1 
where pono = '1' and dueno = '001' or
      pono = '2' and dueno = '001'
```

Alternatively you could have a table/temp table/ table variable with the value pairs to check against using `exists` or if you are in SQL Server 2008 you can do something like this.

```
select *
from table1 as T1
where exists ( 
             select *
             from (values('1','001'),
                         ('2','001')) as T(pono, dueno)
             where T1.pono = T.pono and
                   T1.dueno = T.dueno
             )
```

If you are on PostgreSQL you could use this instead:

```
select *
from table1
where (pono, dueno) in (('1', '001'), ('2', '001'))
```

Comment: Parentheses would be handy in the first query?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Sure they would not hurt and they would clarify what the where clause does but if you put them in the correct positions they will not change the output since `and` has higher precedence than `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd do something like this:

```
select * from table1 where pono in('1','2') and dueno = pono
```

But in your case pono and dueno are different formats so you cannot compare the directly.  There is no difference (or advantage) in doing

```
select * from table1 where pono in('1','2') and dueno in('001','001')
```

compared to

```
select * from table1 where pono in('1','2') and dueno ='001'
```

Comment: but i should match the multiple pono's with multiple dueno's friend.. What should i do for that

Comment: Then I really do not understand what you are asking.  Please edit the question to provide an example table of data and show the results you are looking for.

Comment: i have modified my question.. Please see that and let me know friend

Comment: You did not provide example data or the desired output.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12401086/712765) to another question for an example of how to clearly explain using example data and output.